# How to add axios response data into a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, axios

I'm trying to send an array of URL's asynchronously into an API that shortens URL's and write the responses to a new array, my question is:

How to execute something after all promises are resolved?

**My code**

```
linkList = ['https://www.link1.com', 'https://www.link2.com'];
adsList = []
let ads = async () => {
    const req = axios(apiUrl + linkList)
    const res = await Promise.resolve(req)
    adLinks.push(res.data.shortenedUrl)
    console.log(adsList)
    // Here, it shows a updated array everytime a promise is resolved
}
ads()
console.log(adsList) // Returns [], because the promises aren't resolved by the time it runs
```

I expect to have an array of shortened URLs in `adsList`

Comment: You can use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to execute logic after all promises in array are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `axios` is actually your async request, in which case this should be all you need to get the list of shortened urls:

```
const linkList = ['https://www.link1.com', 'https://www.link2.com'];
const adsList = await Promise.all(
  linkList.map(url => 
    axios(apiUrl + url).then(({data: shortenedUrl}) => shortenedUrl)
  )
);
```